Does the "variance effect" hold for any arbitrary distribution?
Let $F(\mu,\sigma)$ be some two parameter distribution, the parameters are mean and std. All rv below are independent.
Let rv $X_0\sim F(0,\sigma)$ and $X_1\sim F(1,\sigma)$
Let $\sigma'\geq \sigma$.
Let rv $X'_0\sim F(0,\sigma')$ and $X'_1\sim F(1,\sigma')$
This means that all these distributions are from the same location-scale family.
Is it true that  $P(X_1>X_0)\geq P(X'_1>X_0')$?
It clearly works for normal distributions. I wonder if it also work for any arbitrary distributions. Might be a easy question.

Isn't your $X_1$ just $X_0 + 1?$ I think you need to be a bit more specific when you write the parameters are mean and std.

@Dave Yes it is

By the statements, I want to say that the only difference between $X_0'$ and $X_0$ is that the std are difference, while everything else is the same.

The standard deviations change, or the mean changes? If you do mean the standard deviation, then I don't think your claim is even correct for a normal distribution, say $N(0, 1)$ and $N(0, 2)$. Or would you mean $N(0, 1)$ vs $N(1, 1)?$

I will try to be more specific. The mean change between X0 and X1. The std change between X0 and X0'.

"Same ... but has a greater std" is too vague: how does the standard deviation change, exactly?  As an example, many people might say a Gamma(1) and Gamma(2) distribution are "the same" in the sense of being in the same parametric family; and indeed the second has a greater SD than the first--but that's likely not what you have in mind.

@whuber Would it be less vague if I say "$F$ is a distribution with two parameters, mean and std, and $F'$ is the same distribution, with a greater std parameter"?

Less vague, yes--but still not sufficiently definite.  It sounds like you want to state that $F$ and $F^\prime$ are in the same location-scale family and have the same mean.

After your edit $P(X_0+1>X_0)=1=P(X'_0+1>X'_0)$ because $1>0$ so I suspect this is not what you intended to ask about

@whuber Yes you are right! This is exactly what I mean: those distributions are from the same location-scale family with the same mean.

„Let $F(\mu,\sigma)$ be some two parameter distribution“ Is F part of a location scale family?

It is possible to have some weird distribution where $\sigma < 0$ and $\sigma > 0$ make an entirely different type/shape of distribution and it creates an ambiguity.

@SextusEmpiricus Is it possible to give an example?

@HighGPA It is contrived but let
$$X \sim \begin{cases}\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) & \quad \sigma \geq 0 \
\mathcal{M}(\mu, -\sigma) & \quad \sigma < 0
\end{cases}$$
in principle you can use the single parameter $\sigma$ to define an infinite number of location-scale distributions by stacking the variance parameterisation of multiple families such that each uses a subrange of $\sigma$.

I see now that the sentence "the parameters are mean and std. All rv below are independent" can resolve the issue that I mentioned. For the distribution that I described in the previous comment, the $\sigma$ is a parameter but not equal to the standard deviation (which can't be negative). So you are strictly considering location-scale distributions of a form that can be generated out of a single base distribution $F()$ with zero mean and unit variance $$F(x;\mu,\sigma) = F\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

@SextusEmpiricus Many thanks!! I learnt a lot. I will try to be more careful next time!

@HighGPA the error was mainly mine, I saw something in the question that it wasn't.

I think what you are trying to ask something equivalent to:

Suppose $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ are independently identically distributed, and for some given $k\ge 1$ and some $c$ you have $T_i=kS_i+c$ (so the standard deviations of the $T_i$s are $k$ times the standard deviations of the $S_i$s).  Is it always the case that $$P(S_1 +1\ge S_2)\ge P(T_3+1\ge T_4)\,?$$

To which the answer is yes, since
$$\begin{align}
& P(S_1+1\ge S_2) \\
= & P(S_3+1\ge S_4) \\
= & P(kS_3+k\ge kS_4) \\
= & P(kS_3+c+k\ge kS_4+c) \\
= & P(T_3+k\ge T_4) \\
= & P(T_3-T_4\ge -k)\\
\ge  & P(T_3-T_4\ge -1) \\
= & P(T_3+1\ge T_4).
\end{align}$$

+1 short and sweet but I wonder, is there any particular reason you added $+c$?

@LukasLohse: No - if you wish, you can take $c=0$ and it remains true.  I was trying to make this a little more general, so it is true for any location-scale family of distributions when you rescale to increase the dispersion; it does not depend on the expectation taking any particular value or remaining the same or following the scaling (hence the $c$) or even existing.


Instead of making the comparison of variables with a different scale, you can see the equivalent comparison for variables with a different location.

Obviously a larger location makes the probability larger. Let rv $X_0\sim F(0,\sigma)$, $X_a\sim F(a,\sigma)$ and $X_b\sim F(b,\sigma)$, then for $b>a$ we have
$$P(X_b>X_0) \geq P(X_a>X_0)$$

Now to make that shift from comparing variables with different scale to variables with different location, consider a rescaling that preserves the probability but changes the scale and location.
Let rv $X^\dagger_0\sim F(0,\sigma)$ and $X^\dagger_1\sim F(\sigma/\sigma',\sigma)$.
The variables $X^\dagger_0$ and $X^\dagger_1$ are just scaled versions of $X'_0$ and $X'_1$ (by a factor $\sigma/\sigma' < 1$) and we have the equality
$$P(X^\dagger_1>X^\dagger_0) = P(X'_1>X_0')$$
which means instead of comparing $P(X'_1>X_0')$ with $P(X_1>X_0)$, we can also compare $P(X^\dagger_1>X_0^\dagger)$ with $P(X_1>X_0)$.


